# vpn problem in ubuntu

Tags: vpn

i am ubuntu user since 12.04 now i am using 14.04 there is a problem with my PPTP vpn connection since i am using ubuntu, in my University i have to use vpn in order to connect to the internet but when i connect to vpn in ubuntu i can use internet for about 30 seconds then i cannot open webpages or my download speed gets to 0 but at the same time in windows i can connect and download or view webpages easily with no problem 
i need your help cause i am doing most of my works with ubuntu
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give the exact steps you were using for your VPN connection.

Follow these steps:

VPN Client Setup:

Fourconfiguration files are involved:

- /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn
- /etc/ppp/options.pptp
- /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
- /etc/ppp/ip-up.local

/etc/ppp/peers/myvpn:

```
# replace the bracket paramters with the host name of the VPN server and VPN user
remotename myvpn
linkname myvpn
ipparam myvpn
pty "pptp [vpn server] --nolaunchpppd "
name [username]
usepeerdns
require-mppe
refuse-eap
noauth

# adopt defaults from the pptp-linux package
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
```

/etc/ppp/options.pptp:

```
lock
noauth
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
```

/etc/ppp/chap-secrets:

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client server secret IP addresses
username myvpn password *
```

/etc/ppp/ip-up.local:

```
#!/bin/sh
network=`echo $IPREMOTE | awk -F\. '{print $1"."$2"."$3".0/24"}'`
route add -net $network $IFNAME
```

Start the VPN client with:

```
$ sudo pon myvpn
```

End VPN connection with:

```
$ sudo poff myvpn
```

These steps are taken from:

http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/vpn/

Comment: i tried that,it didnt work